# Что творится с colorama в линуксе

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли это как-то поправить

> под словом поправить я имею ввиду чтобы цветом выделялась строчка а не
>   всё

```
print(Back.GREEN+Style.BRIGHT+'Файл '+id_pic+' успешно скачан')
```

Comment: да это работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указание цвета действует вплоть до следующего его изменения. Если вам нужно выделить фон только выводимого текста, добавьте в конце каждого вывода изменение на черный цвет фона:

```
print(Back.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT + 'Файл ' + id_pic + ' успешно скачан' + Back.BLACK)
```